# Find all sequences with properties as follows

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

Given $d\in\mathbb{N}^+$, find all strictly increasing sequences of positive integers $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ such that the sequence $\{p_n\}_{n\ge 1}$, defined by
$$p_n:=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=a_n+1}^{a_{n+1}} a_i\right)-da_{a_n},~n\ge 1$$ is bounded, and takes every value in the range infinitely many times.

---

Random thoughts: Assume $|p_n|\leq P$ for some $P>0$ for any $n$.
Then we have $P\geq p_n>(a_{n+1}-a_n-d)a_{a_n}$, here we use the fact that $\{a_n\}$ is increasing. Letting $n\to\infty$, we have $a_{n+1}-a_n\leq d$ for sufficient large $n$.
Conversely, we have
$-P\leq p_n\leq (a_{n+1}-a_n)a_{a_{n+1}}-d(a_{a_{n+1}}-a_{a_n})= (a_{n+1}-a_n-d)a_{a_{n+1}}+d(a_{a_{n+1}}-a_{a_n})\leq (a_{n+1}-a_n-d)a_{a_{n+1}}+d^3$

for large enough $n$. So again, by letting $n\to \infty$, we have $a_{n+1}-a_n\geq d$ for large $n$.

Now how to deal with the first finite many terms? I guess we should use the second property of $\{p_n\}$?

---

I think I have a solution in mind that might work, will type it up sometime tomorrow. The key point is, $p_n$ is constant eventually, and the second property forces $p_n$ to be a constant.

Perhaps we can sharp the condition even more? say we just assume $|p_n-p_m|\leq d^2$ for all pairs of $m,n$?

Comment: Please provide more context, in particular what you have tried and your thoughts on this. Problem statement questions like this are frowned upon here.

Comment: Thanks, I believe $a_n=a_1+d(n-1)$ are the solutions, this yields $p_n=d^2(d+1)/2$ a constant sequence. The hard part is to show these are the only possible sequence.

Comment: Why do you think those are the only ones? Also you could edit the question to make it easier to see what you’re saying.

Comment: you can try to use the strictly increasing to reduce the starting n as much as possible to the equality $a_n - a_{n-1} = d$, so in your estimate for $a_{n+1} - a_n - d$, you will get an extra term as well. You should be able to show P cannot be greater than a multiple of the constant $p_n$, otherwise there is no way to traverse all values in between.

Comment: Thanks Yimin, I think we can reduce to the case $p_n$ is constant, and it is $d^2(d+1)/2$, and we may use reverse induction to conclude.